# How can I add files to a listView from the Main Form using C#?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, listview

I have a software in C# that has a main form (meaning the form that opens when you start a software like almost every software has). However, the main form opens a form called `ProjectFiles` . I would like to know if it is possible to add files to the `listView` in `ProjectFiles` from the main form. I have tried searching the internet for how to do this but everyone has been asking how to do it a different way. I have also tried doing this without help so here is my code but the problem is when I use this code, the software will stop responding.

main form:

```
public string[] lines { get; set; }
void projectFilesToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.parentForm == null)
      {
        return;
      }
    if(opfd.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string[]lines = File.ReadAllLines(opfd.FileName);
    }
}
```

ProjectFiles:

```
void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MainForm mf = new MainForm();
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(mf.lines.ToString());
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            listView1.Items.Add(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Edit:
I was asked to post exactly what the error is in more detail. Like I said above, the software becomes greyed out, and a message box shows up saying it has stopped responding. If this is not clear enough, please let me know.

Edit: I have tried the below asnwers but the software still continues to do the same. It seems like too much for the software to handle.

Comment: Just create a method on the second form that allows you to pass a file or whatever, then that form can modify its own controls.  Otherwise, "it crashes" is a terrible problem description.

Comment: Your generating a new mainform in the project files.   remember when you create a new object it is an entirely new instance of that object by creating a `new MainForm()` then accessing the new one,  it's going to be blank in the location your looking for things,  hence the reason it crashes.   my guess is your getting some kind of null error.  if this isn't correct,  at least post the error so we can try and assist.

Comment: Dear Landon, are you trying to add list items from the main form or are you just trying to show the ProjectFiles form and fill the list view in it? Your question is really confusing this way.

Comment: I am trying to get items to show up by using mainform in a listView inside another form that is opened.

Comment: @Landon-Conway is ProjectFiles a child form of Mainform?

Comment: @landon-conway then my answer should justify. Why the downvotes I wonder..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, when you call ShowDialog() to display a form, any code after this statement will not execute until that form is closed. See the Remarks section of [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx)

Therefore, it is not possible to add files to the list view in the ProjectFiles from the MainForm in your case (ShowDialog)

But if you need to do that;

1. Change the access modifier of the listView1 in ProjectFiles to public
2. Keep the pointer to the ProjectFiles form as a member variable in MainForm

   ProjectFiles theProjectFiles = new ProjectFiles();
3. Display the ProjectFiles form with .Show() instead of .ShowDialog()

   theProjectFiles.Show();
4. Just use the listView1 in ProjectFiles form as usual:

   theProjectFiles.listView1.Add(...);